# Is there a way to have a single link to Google fonts with wildcard?

Tags: css, fonts

On the google fonts websites, they say that you need to have a link per font set...

So like this:

```
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And then put in the HTML:

```
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

So for EVERY font I need a link to Google CSS?

Isn't there a wildcard like:

```
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css/*' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Is that possible, am I missing something here?

Comment: There are 804 font families on Google Fonts right now. Do you need all of them all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load multiple google fonts in one URL, just separate each font using **`|`** character.

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic|Roboto:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, perfect!